# how to enable shift-arrow for org-timestamp-up and org-timestamp-down in Emacs org-mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, aquamacs

In Emacs org-mode, how do I instruct org to enable <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>  for `org-timestamp-up` and `org-timestamp-down`?

I have the value of `org-support-shift-select` set to `Everywhere except timestamps` and I thought that would do it, but when I <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>, it just highlights my timestamp instead of upping it.

(I'm using Aquamacs on OSX.)

Answer (score 0):

You could add local key bindings, maybe?
Or use shift-up or shift-down?